# clear currently edited line in mysql console

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, mysql, putty

What key combination will clear MySQL console command line?

I am not sure if this is just a sub scenario of clearing the currently edited line in any Unix/Linux terminal or is the behavior actually different when you are running MySQL command or maybe it depends on the terminal app I am running...

Anyway, I am using a Debian lenny Linux box running MySQL command prompt and this is all done from  windows via putty.

Often while editing the SQL I am writing I want to just "reset" the current edit and start over.

I know I can press End and then enough Backspace until the row is clear but was looking for something faster...

I also know that pressing Ctrl+C kills the mysql console and I can then press the up arrow to get the command that executed the console and start it over. but this feels like an over kill (and also renders quite a lot of text to the screen...).

thanks.

Comment: what happens if you press Ctrl+U ?

Comment: it trims to the beginning of the line - which is not bad it means I can press end and then CRTL+U and get what I want. If I don't get a single key combination that does this regardless of where in the line you are then you can post as an answer and I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am not sure if this is just a sub scenario of clearing the currently edited line in any Unix/Linux terminal or is the behavior actually different when you are running MySQL command or maybe it depends on the terminal app I am running...

It isn't dependent from your terminal emulator; MySQL is different but not to what you might think; and it's not a subset.

### Background

Simple Unix and Linux programs just `read()` from standard input for their input.  The historical convention is that terminals in Unix and Linux normally operate in what is known colloquially by its historical name "cooked mode" and what is formally and properly known as "canonical mode".  In this mode, a part of the kernel known as the *line discipline* does all of the line editing, and the program only receives the final edited line from `read()` when the user sends the *end-of-line character* (normally `LF`) from the terminal.

In canonical mode, there are a whole load of special characters that the line discipline recognizes and acts specially upon.  The end-of-line character is but one.  Another is *kill character*.  This "kills" the (line discipline's) editing buffer.  Since the cursor *can only be* at the end of the line, the line discipline's editing facility not having mechanisms for moving a cursor within the line being edited, this kills the entire line.

Back in the 1980s and 1990s, people wanted a better TUI than this.  They wanted the ability to move the cursor within the line.  They wanted insert/overstrike modes.  They wanted command history.

Thus along came GNU Readline and its ilk.  GNU Readline is a library that is used by a number of popular programs including the Bourne Again shell and the `mysql` command.  Readline switches the terminal into what is colloquially known by the historical name "raw mode" (the formal name being "non-canonical mode").  The program `read()`s the characters from the terminal as they are sent, without any intervening processing by the line discipline.  Readline does all of the editing, outwith the kernel.

Nowadays, terminals spend quite a lot of their time in non-canonical mode.  They do when modern shells are reading their input.  (Not all modern shells use Readline.  But they all have something which uses non-canonical mode.  The Z Shell has its own mechanism, ZLE.  BSD-licensed programs use the BSD `libedit` library, which Christos Zoulas took from the Tenex C Shell for 4.4BSD, or Editline.)  They do when programs that use `ncurses` are active.  Canonical mode is predominantly encountered by people when they do things like accidentally `grep` the terminal, or use `cat` to create a file from terminal input, and is heading towards being the exception more than the norm.

In the usual case, Readline reads all of the special keys from the line discipline and creates *key bindings* (mappings from character sequences to editing actions) that match the special characters to actions that do the same as what the line discipline would have done in canonical mode.

You can see what the line discipline thinks that the special characters are with the `stty -a` command.  In particular, it will tell you what your `kill` special character is.  It's commonly <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> the ASCII `NAK` character.  Symbolically, this special character is known as `VKILL`, from the name of the constant used to set it in C and C++ programs.

Usually, Readline (or `libedit`, or ZLE, or Editline) will have a binding from the line discipline's `VKILL` character to one of its "kill" actions.  In fact, unless Readline's `bind-tty-special-characters` variable is off, it will redefine such a binding *every time that it is called to read a fresh line of input*.  It's actually hard to turn this off.

There are three caveats.

1. These libraries are *libraries*.  They have various program-controlled tuning knobs available, and so programs can employ them in subtly different ways.
2. The `mysql` command can be compiled with *either* GNU Readline *or* `libedit`.  If it's compiled with `libedit` then the conventional key binding is from `VKILL` to the `em-kill-line` action.  This kills the entire line and does what you want.
3. If `mysql` is compiled with GNU Readline, the `VKILL` special character is conventionally bound to `unix-line-discard`.  This doesn't do exactly what you want, however, because it only erases *from the current cursor position* to the beginning of the line.  Of course, this is indistinguishable from the line discipline's action in canonical mode if one only sticks to what that can do, because *the cursor position is always the end of the line*.

### Answer

- If `mysql` was built with Readline:

  - The conventional <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (or whatever `stty -a` says to be your `kill` character) will get you Readline's `unix-line-discard` action.  This doesn't do exactly what you want, because it only erases *from the current cursor position* to the beginning of the line.
  - The action that you actually want is Readline's `kill-whole-line`, which deletes the whole line, regardless of the cursor position.
  - Unfortunately, `kill-whole-line` isn't bound to your `VKILL` character, or indeed to any character by default; and Readline will reset the binding of `VKILL` back to `unix-line-discard` every time that you start a fresh line of input, unless you set `bind-tty-special-chars` off and lose the automatic mirroring of what special characters are set in the line discipline by `stty`.
  - So bind some *other* character sequence of your choosing to `kill-whole-line` in your `~/.inputrc` file, unless you are happy with the effects of `bind-tty-special-chars` being off.
- If `mysql` was built with `libedit`:

  - As long as you are in "emacs" mode, the conventional <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (or whatever `stty -a` says to be your `kill` character) will get you `libedit`'s `em-kill-line` action ("emacs kill line").  This does exactly what you want.
  - You don't have to do anything in `libedit`'s `~/.editrc` file.
  - In "vi" mode, your `VKILL` character is bound to `libedit`'s `vi-kill-line-prev` action ("vi kill line up to cursor").

None of this involves your terminal emulator in any way.

### Further reading

- Jess Thrysoee (2013). [*Editline*](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/)
- [*editrc(5)*](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=editrc&sektion=5).  FreeBSD Manual Pages.  FreeBSD Project.
- Chet Ramey (2013).  [*The GNU Readline Library*](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).
- [*The General Terminal Interface*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html).  The Open Group Base Specifications.  Version 7.  IEEE Std 1003.1.  2013.
- Peter Stephenson (2003-03-23).  ["The Z-Shell Line Editor"](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html).  *A User's Guide to the Z-Shell*.
- ["input line editing"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-tips.html#mysql-input-editing).  *MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual*.  2014.  Oracle corporation.

Comment: WOW, This was very thorough. Thanks for the very good explanation.
I love understanding stuff, just knowing is not always enough...
I suppose from what I see that my mysql command line is built on `libedit`. but anyway I can live with <end>,CTRL+U.

Answer (score 4):

Some useful shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> : delete previous word, repeat until the line is empty
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>K</kbd> : Kill everything after the current position of the cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> : go to the beginning of the line. Combine with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>K</kbd> to delete it. I usually just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down and hit <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> one after the other.

You may also be ineterested in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112064/22222) answer on U&L.se and in the keybindings shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the keybindings image. It would surely make me more productive. I also liked finding out about the `kbd` tag for rendering keys...